# Codenerix - Deshabilitar un campo dropdown a una foreign key usando ng-readonly

Tags: python, angularjs, django

## Codenerix

¿Alguien sabe como usar correctamente ng-readonly en un GenModelForm cuando se llama desde un sublist tab (GenList) que a su vez invoca a una ventana CreateModal?

La estructura es maestro-detalle. La sublista tiene la pk de la tabla maestro y llama al GenCreateModal con la pk de dicha tabla maestro.

GenCreateModal recibe el argumento pk en su formulario asociado (el GenModelForm mencionado anteriormente) y la usa para rellenar el campo. El objetivo es deshabilitar el campo con ng-disabled si se pasa la pk de la tabla maestra y asignarle dicho valor. De esta forma, cuando llamamos a la creación desde un sublist podemos bloquear el campo y obligar a asignar el dato de la tabla maestra y si se llama desde un mantenimiento propio sin indicar la pk de la tabla maestra podemos seleccionarlo al no estar bloqueado.

He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

Primero asignar 'client' en GenCreateModal con:

```
def get_initial(self): 
    client = self.kwargs.get('pk', None) 
    if client: 
        self.kwargs['client'] = client 
    return self.kwargs
```

Después leerlo en el GenModelform con:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
    super(DetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if kwargs.get('initial', None) and kwargs['initial'].get('client', None):
        self.fields['client'].widget.attrs[u'ng-readonly'] = 'true'
```

Pero no funciona correctamente, el desplegable está habilitado y se puede modificar el valor. Se puede hacer debido a que en templatetags_list.py de codenerix tenemos:

```
def inireadonly(attrs, i):
    field = ngmodel(i)
    return addattr(attrs, 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field))
```

Este código establece ng-readonly a "true readonly_client" en vez de "true" cuando viene con el valor "true" ya asignado desde GenModelForm, los valores se están concatenando.

He encontrado un workaround para forzarlo con:

```
self.fields['client'].widget.attrs[u'ng-readonly'] = 'true || '
```

de esta forma el valor concatenado será "true || readonly_client" que resulta en "true" al evaluarlo, pero no creo que sea la manera correcta.

En un fork local de django-codenerix he cambiado la función inireadonly a (cuidado que está duplicada, habría que cambiarla en los dos sitios):

```
def inireadonly(attrs, i):
    field = ngmodel(i)
    if attrs.get('ng-readonly', None) is None:
        attrs = addattr(attrs, 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field))
    return attrs
```

De esta forma se respeta el valor cuando viene cumplimentado desde GenModelForm, pero no estoy seguro de que sea correcto y no produzca efectos colaterales, por ejemplo cuando se quieren concatenar valores a la expresión, esto obligaría a leer el antiguo, concatenar lo que queremos y establecerlo. Pienso que debe haber una forma mejor de hacerlo y que además la expresión 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field) tiene alguna funcionalidad que desconozco, no quiero romperla ni perderla el día que la averigüe, así que deshice los cambios en busca de una mejor solución.

Actualmente estoy usando:

```
self.fields['client'].widget.attrs[u'ng-disabled'] = 'true'
```

y funciona perfectamente, ya no tengo problemas al deshabilitar el campo, pero me ha quedado la curiosidad sobre la forma correcta de usarlo con ng-readonly si lo necesito en un futuro debido a que con ng-readonly se permite seleccionar texto en los campos con el ratón para poder copiarlo en otros sitios y con ng-disabled no se permite, esta funcionalidad en algunos casos puede ser interesante.

¿Sabe alguien como usar ng-readonly con django-codenerix de una forma correcta?
¿Sabe alguien la funcionalidad de 'ng-readonly=readonly_{0}'.format(field)?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar **ng-disabled** tal cual lo usas ahora mismo. Este es el modo en que nosotros lo usamos en [Ejemplos de Django Codenerix @ Gibhub](https://github.com/centrologic/django-codenerix-examples/blob/master/exchange/exchange/base/forms.py) (líneas 41 y 42) y este es el modo en el que también está desarrollado en los **[StaticSelects](https://github.com/centrologic/django-codenerix/blob/master/codenerix/widgets.py)** (línea 228).

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo un **GenModelForm**, cuando definas los **__groups__**, uno de los parámetros que le puedes pasar a los campos es **{'extra': ['ng-disabled=true']}**. Ejemplo:

```
def __groups__(self):
    g = [
        (_('Info'), 12,
            ['client', 6, {'extra': ['ng-disabled=true']}],
        )
    ]
    return g
```